# Sending email with Sinatra error

Tags: javascript, ruby, email, sinatra

I'm new to Ruby and Sinatra and am trying to send an email every time someone presses the submit button. I installed the Pony gem based on the sinatra website and other questions asked here, but when I try to send it sends me to a page with a picture of a spilled glass that says:

```
"Errno::ENOENT at /submit
No such file or directory - which sendmail
file: pony.rb location: ` line: 305"
```

Here is my code

```
post '/submit' do
  subject = Subject.new(
  :experiment_data => params[:data],
  :created_at => Time.now
  )
  if subject.save
    session[:subj_id] = subject.id
    require 'pony'
    Pony.mail(:to => 'toemail@gmail.com', :from => 'fromemail@yahoo.com', :subject => 'Waz up')
    redirect '/submit'
  else
    return "Failed to save data"
  end
end

get '/submit' do
   if session[:subj_id]
    subj_id = session[:subj_id]
    code = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest "#{subj_id}"
    erb :submit, :locals => {:code => code, :subj_id => subj_id}
  else
    redirect '/'    
  end
end
```

Is this the best way to do this? The email I'm trying to send has lots of variable that will need to be filled out with data coming from javascript variables on the html page. I'm thinking of using an erb template, but I'm not really sure how this would work.

Answer (score 0):

[Somewhere in the Pony gem](https://github.com/benprew/pony/blob/master/lib/pony.rb#L304-L307) they try to find the program location by running the command `which sendmail`, so they can forward the email to be sent out by `sendmail`. The error probably means that the `sendmail` command line program is not installed on your system. It is now up to you to figure out how to install it on your specific system ;-)

Comment: I tried installing pony, sendmail, and mailcatcher gems this but I'm still getting the same error message.